# Can't get the params from components to the target route

Tags: vue.js, parameters, router

I have a menu which is imported to the home and mine page. In home page I passed a data(user_id) to the menu.

```html
<li>
    <router-link to="/">
        <i></i>
        <div class="icon home"></div>
        <span class="text">Home</span>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li>
    <router-link :to="{ path: '/mine', params: {id: user_id} }">
        <i></i>
        <div class="icon user"></div>
        <span class="text">Mine</span>
    </router-link>
</li>
```

On mine page, when I tried to display the params in console, it doesn't show.
but If the passing of data is from home to mine page it works.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

**Structure**

- components

  - menu
- views

  - home
  - mine

Comment: You can only use `params` with named routes, eg `:to="{ name: 'mine', params: { ... } }"`

Comment: you're right bro thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<router-link :to="`/mine/${user_id}`">
```

to see information about your route try this command
`console.log(this.$route)`

Comment: anytime, dont forget to accept my answer if that's the correct answer..